# Sumif based on multiple conditions in excel

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010, sumifs

| Material | Region | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| M1 | Region1 | 100 |
| M1 | Region2 | 200 |
| M1 | Region4 | 200 |
| M2 | Region3 | 150 |
| M3 | Region3 | 75 |
| M4 | Region6 | 200 |
| M5 | Region3 | 100 |

From the table above i have to calculate the sum of sales from different groups. First condition of a group is that it can have same Material value but different Region values, so M1-Region1, M1-Region2,M1-Region4 , sum of these combinations would be 500, all of these combinations should have 500 on the sum column. Second condition for a group is that it can have different Material values but same Region values, so M2-Region3, M3-Region3,M5-Region3- sum of these combinations from sales column would be 325, all of these combinations should show 325 on the sum column, M4-Region 6 doesnt have any other combinations so it remains a stand alone combination, sum column value should be same as Sales column value which is 200. So the output would like a below table. Could you please help to have a sumif formula that address these conditions

Output table should be like this

| Material | Region | Sales | Sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| M1 | Region1 | 100 | 500 |
| M1 | Region2 | 200 | 500 |
| M1 | Region4 | 200 | 500 |
| M2 | Region3 | 150 | 325 |
| M3 | Region3 | 75 | 325 |
| M4 | Region6 | 200 | 200 |
| M5 | Region3 | 100 | 325 |

Please advise on this problem. Thank you
[image]

| Material | Region | Sales | Formula |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| M1 | Region1 | 100 | 500 |
| M1 | Region2 | 200 | 500 |
| M1 | Region4 | 200 | 500 |
| M2 | Region3 | 150 | 325 |
| M3 | Region3 | 75 | 325 |
| M4 | Region6 | 200 | 200 |
| M5 | Region3 | 100 | 325 |
| M6 | Region5 | 100 | 600 |
| M7 | Region7 | 200 | 200 |
| M8 | Region5 | 200 | 500 |
| M8 | Region5 | 300 | 500 |

[image]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Comment: i have tried doing sumifs but it gets trickier when you have multiple conditions

Comment: it shouldn't.  Post the formula you tried and the results.  It will help w/ the debugging.

Comment: What would you expect if `M2` would've been `Region 4`?

Comment: If M2 was in Region 4, then M1-Region1, M1-Region2,M1-Region4 and M2-Region4 would all be in one group- then all these combinations should have same sum value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:
This will get the results you need in older excel:

```
=SUM(INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$2:$C$9)/(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$2:$A$9,INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$2:$C$9)/ISNUMBER(MATCH($B$2:$B$9,INDEX(B:$B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$2:$C$9)/($A$2:$A$9=A2),ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,SUMPRODUCT(N($A$2:$A$9=A2)))))),0)),ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(MATCH($B$2:$B$9,INDEX(B:$B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$2:$C$9)/($A$2:$A$9=A2),ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,SUMPRODUCT(N($A$2:$A$9=A2)))))),0))))))),0))),ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$2:$A$9,INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$2:$C$9)/ISNUMBER(MATCH($B$2:$B$9,INDEX(B:$B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$2:$C$9)/($A$2:$A$9=A2),ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,SUMPRODUCT(N($A$2:$A$9=A2)))))),0)),ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(MATCH($B$2:$B$9,INDEX(B:$B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$2:$C$9)/($A$2:$A$9=A2),ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,SUMPRODUCT(N($A$2:$A$9=A2)))))),0))))))),0))))))))
```

I know, It's a wall of formula.

Basically it filters out all Regions for current row's Machine. Then it filters out all Machines associated with the filtered Regions. Finally it checks which rows belong to these filtered Regions and sum the rows of the sales column for these columns.

Office 365 would be like this:
`=MAP(A2:A9,LAMBDA(a,LET(r,FILTER(B2:B9,A2:A9=a),LET(m,UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A9,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(B2:B9,r)))),SUM(FILTER(C2:C9,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(A2:A9,m))))))))`

[image]

or for the new added table:

```
=SUM(INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$2:$C$12)/(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$2:$A$12,INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$2:$C$12)/ISNUMBER(MATCH($B$2:$B$12,INDEX(B:$B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$2:$C$12)/($A$2:$A$12=A2),ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,SUMPRODUCT(N($A$2:$A$12=A2)))))),0)),ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(MATCH($B$2:$B$12,INDEX(B:$B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$2:$C$12)/($A$2:$A$12=A2),ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,SUMPRODUCT(N($A$2:$A$12=A2)))))),0))))))),0))),ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$2:$A$12,INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$2:$C$12)/ISNUMBER(MATCH($B$2:$B$12,INDEX(B:$B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$2:$C$12)/($A$2:$A$12=A2),ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,SUMPRODUCT(N($A$2:$A$12=A2)))))),0)),ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(MATCH($B$2:$B$12,INDEX(B:$B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$2:$C$12)/($A$2:$A$12=A2),ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,SUMPRODUCT(N($A$2:$A$12=A2)))))),0))))))),0))))))))
```

Comment: When pasting the screenshot I realized that `Region4` counts all for `M1`, but not in case of `M3`. In other words it doesn't pick up duplicates of the Machines other than for it's own machine.

Comment: This would work in Office 365:

`=MAP(A2:A9,LAMBDA(a,LET(r,FILTER(B2:B9,A2:A9=a),LET(m,UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A9,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(B2:B9,r)))),SUM(FILTER(C2:C9,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(A2:A9,m))))))))`

Comment: See edit for solution. Hope it's what you're after. Definately not straightforward, lol. Nice challenge.

Comment: Thank you so much @P.b it worked like wonders.  Apparently The sum(index) formula worked on office 365 as well. Also another question would be why is there a specific number like 15,6 inside Aggregate function on the first formula?

Comment: 15 is to declare the type of aggregation: SMALL and 6 is to ignore error values. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aggregate-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df but if you have Office 365 I would recommend using the other suggested formula.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was commendable what you did. Only if i could learn all of this :D. I was having hard time interpreting this formula :D

Comment: =MAP(B3:B14,LAMBDA(a,LET(r,FILTER(C3:C14,B3:B14=a),LET(m,UNIQUE(FILTER(B3:B14,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(C3:C14,r)))),SUM(FILTER(E3:E14,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(B3:B14,m)))))))) in this formula how to automatically update cell references, i mean can i use C:C, B:B instead of C3:C14 and B3:B14

Comment: Then I'd go for something like: `=MAP(DROP(TOCOL(A:A,1),1),LAMBDA(x,LET(r,FILTER(DROP(TOCOL(B:B,1),1),DROP(TOCOL(A:A,1),1)=x),LET(m,UNIQUE(FILTER(DROP(TOCOL(A:A,1),1),ISNUMBER(XMATCH(DROP(TOCOL(B:B,1),1),r)))),SUM(FILTER(DROP(TOCOL(C:C,1),1),ISNUMBER(XMATCH(DROP(TOCOL(A:A,1),1),m))))))))` Note that no other data may be in any of the columns and they all have headers/values in the rows where other columns have data.

Comment: Thank you so much @P.b Genius!!!. I would like to close this thread as it solved my problem. Also I would like to learn these user defined functions in excel. Is there any proper literature available online to learn more about this. Would highly appreciate all your time and effort. Thanks again!!

Comment: It's really combining different functions. It's good to start doing things involving helper columns. Once you get the hang of it, you can combine steps

Comment: It's better not to tag Excel 2010 if you have Office 365. As you see the older Excel doesn't have the same functionality and possibilities are limited or way more complicated and less efficient.

Answer (score 3):

As already suggested it is pretty straight forward to resolve it. Use SUMIFS and IF

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$8,A2)>1,SUMIFS($C$2:$C$8,$A$2:$A$8,A2),SUMIFS($C$2:$C$8,$B$2:$B$8,B2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you William. but for M1- Region 4, the formula shows 200 instead of 500 and for all Region 3 combinations with different Material values it shows different sum values instead of 325

Comment: Hi, i have modified the formula

Comment: thanks again William. It worked for the first condition, but for the second condition it still shows the sum as 225, whereas it should be 325 for all Region 3 combinations. M2-Region3, M3-Region3 and M5-Region3- all these combinations should show 325

Comment: where do ya see, image shows 325 for all region 3 combinations

Comment: when i tried your formula- it gives me the sum as 225 for M2- Region 3, M3-Region 3 and 100 for M5- Region 3. However it should be 325 for all these combinations

Comment: you can see my answer picture evidently shows your result

Comment: i use the same formula but i get different values for region 3 combinations. totally weird. I have added picture of my output above

Comment: @ArvindMenon The error is in your data. `Region 3` contains a space character for `M5` unlike the other values for `Region3`

Comment: i just figured it out. thank you so much William and P.b

Comment: Well credits to @William. But this won't work if you have mixed region and material repeats, as commented (`M2` being `region4`). Would that happen in your data?

Comment: Thank you. That won't happen to my dataset. But there is again a discrepancy in the formula. I have added four new combinations after M5-Region3. It seems like formula is updating only 500 as sum for M8-Region5 combinations instead of 600. Any thoughts on why is this happening and how we could address it please

Comment: That's exactly what I ment. You have both duplicate Material numbers with various regions and duplicate regions with various material.
This formula was designed to work with either Material duplicates or Region duplicates. Let me post an answer.